# how to extract body part from email in php?

Tags: java, php

This is my function which is in PHP and I want to extract Body Part of the email message. The Function accepts an object which is msg whose type is **MimeMessage**.
I want to extract body part from this message then convert it to a String and then concatenate this String with another String and then add this final concatenated String into the body of an another new object which is **newMsg** whose type is also MimeMessage.

```
private function handleQuestion(MimeMessage msg)
{
    $this->log->debug('ListProcessor: Entered handleQuestion()');
    $this->log->info('Processing Question: ' + getMsgLogInfo(msg));

    // To handle a question just send it on to the list server.
    // It will take care of the rest of the processing.

    try
    {
        // Ensure that this question didn't come from the staging mailbox.
        // This could cause an e-mail loop situation.
        String stagingAddress=(String)$this->runConfig.get('stagingMailboxAddress');
        FromStringTerm fromSearch = new FromStringTerm(stagingAddress);

        if (fromSearch.match(msg))
        {
            $this->log->warn('Message sent from staging mailbox: sending to admin');
            sendToListAdmin(msg, MSGERR_FROM_STAGING);
        }
        else
        {
            // String msgSubject = msg.getSubject();
            // String subject = translateRFC2231Subject(msgSubject);
            String subject = translateRFC2231Subject(getSubjectLines(msg));




            // Create a new message, initialized using the one from the mailbox
            MimeMessage newMsg = new MimeMessage((MimeMessage)msg);

            // Redirect it to the List Server
            newMsg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                            new InternetAddress((String)runConfig.get('publicListAddress')));
            // Remove any CC/BCC addresses
            newMsg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, '');
            newMsg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, '');
            newMsg.setSubject(subject);


            mailTransport.send(newMsg);

            // Update the threadTracker.
            InternetAddress author = (InternetAddress)msg.getFrom()[0];
            MessageThreadData threadData = new MessageThreadData((InternetAddress)author, new Date());
            threadTracker.put(subject.trim(), threadData);
            $this->log->info('Started New Thread: ' + getMsgLogInfo(msg));

            $this->newThreadCount++;

            $this->log->info('Question Processed Successfully');
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        $this->errorCount++;
        $this->log->error('Question Processing Failed', ex);
    }

    $this->log->debug('ListProcessor: Exiting handleQuestion()');
}
```

I want to add something like **newMsg.setBody(bodyText)**

**Note**: I am not sure whether MimeMessage type in the given Function is a Java object or PHP object because the function declaration is in the PHP form.

Comment: not trying to be cruel, but your code is neither php nor java. not php: var in function signature has no $, not java: some vars have $.

Comment: Can you please tell me what exactly this code is of type because I am re-engineering existing code and I am no able to get exact answer for this

Comment: well ... its somehow both. some of the syntax definitely looks like Java and some of it absolutely looks like php. Does this code actually run anywhere? Because it seems like you're fishing ...

Comment: Its actually running on a live server. Is there any other way through which I can achieve my solution ?. I mean any bridging mechanism or interface between Java or PHP

Comment: the point is, your problem description is so unspecific and the context so completely unknown, that I won't even attempt to solve it. find someone who actually works with your code.

Comment: Simply saying I want to extract body part of Email message from the object (MimeMessage msg)  and convert it into a string